# More temperature after boil the water can cook more faster the food?

Tags: thermodynamics, soft-question

I have a dispute with my girlfriend about this we are both systems engineers (just for the records), i want to cook more efficient wasting less ( gas or electricty ) and she want to cook faster.

Nice. my logic here is if after boil the water the heat is 100° costant then the flame can be reduce for not waste energy. but if remain high the food would could cook faster and is an equilibrium of energy-time correlation.

Who way wins or it is equal?

and apologies for the bad use of physics language i did not explored too much thermodynamics....

Comment: No, cooking is determined by T (you can look at the thermodynamics or at the kinetics. If you cannot rise the water T (pressure cooker, salt) nothing change between the two procedures if not wasting. The answer below is OK but I stress that your logic is based on a false assumption.

Comment: so are you saying that if i pressure the cooker i need more heat for boil right? but what is the limit for avoid the wasting? when to stop the heat? do you have the laws or some references about that? this is what subject of thermo?

Comment: Basically simmering does not waste..I thought you had some reasoning behind so I commented. But the answer is basically that below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best would be to reduce the heat to the minimum needed to just keep the water boiling (simmering), lots of cookers have a simmer setting.  If it's kept high, the water temperature doesn't increase above 100C and you'll just fill the kitchen with steam!

Salt water boils at a slightly higher temperature but that's unhealthy, so lots of factors to consider, depends on your preferences.  Bon Appetit!